# core data dynamic predicate: passing data?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate

Here's my scenario:
I have a "cameras" table view and a "Rolls" table view. I want to click on a camera and load it's corresponding rolls. I can't seem to get this to work. What is the proper way to pass the selected camera core data object into the predicate of the rolls table view NSFetchedResultsController?

**Camera entity**

*relationship* : rolls

*Destination* :Roll

*Inverse* : No Inverse

**Roll entity**

*relationship* : camera

*Destination* :Camera

*Inverse* : No Inverse

**from roll table view controller**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Roll" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"desc" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];    

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY camera == %@", self.selectedCamera.objectID];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Have you defined a relationship between the `camera` and a `roll`?

Comment: @Flexicoder I've edited the question with the relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relationships should each have an inverse (in this case, be inverse of each other). This allows Core Data to properly manage the relationship and allows you to set it conveniently while navigating it in both directions. It also properly represents the relationship.

The predicate should be:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"camera == %@", self.selectedCamera];
```

to use the `camera` relationship on the `Roll` entity and check that it contains the provided `self.selectedCamera` entity instance.

Comment: Ok. I've corrected my entity relationships and predicate. I suppose that was the first part of my problem. The second is, what is the recommended way to pass the clicked camera object to the rolls table controller?

Comment: Segue? You get the object just like you do to populate the camera table, pass it in prepare for segue or when the roll view controller is created.

Comment: Thanks. You don't even want to know how I was attempting this

Comment: In this case, not really, because you have shown code in the question which shows effort and your additional question wasn't big :-)

Comment: no, I was joking about the ridiculous way I was trying to pass the object :-)